# Future vs Thread: Which is better for working with channels in core.async?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, clojure, core.async

When working with channels, is `future` recommended or is `thread`? Are there times when `future` makes more sense?

Rich Hickey's blog post on core.async recommends using `thread` rather than `future`:

> While you can use these operations on threads created with e.g. future, there is also a macro, thread , analogous to go, that will launch a first-class thread and similarly return a channel, and should be preferred over future for channel work.

~ http://clojure.com/blog/2013/06/28/clojure-core-async-channels.html

However, a core.async example makes extensive use of `future` when working with channels:

```
(defn fake-search [kind]
  (fn [c query]
    (future
     (<!! (timeout (rand-int 100)))
     (>!! c [kind query]))))
```

~ https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/examples/ex-async.clj

Comment: I think the blog post URL you want is now https://clojure.org/news/2013/06/28/clojure-clore-async-channels

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Summary

In general, `thread` with its channel return will likely be more convenient for the parts of your application where channels are prominent. On the other hand, any subsystems in your application that interface with some channels at their boundaries but don't use core.async internally should feel free to launch threads in whichever way makes the most sense for them.

#### Differences between `thread` and `future`

As pointed out in the fragment of the core.async blog post you quote, `thread` returns a channel, just like `go`:

```
(let [c (thread :foo)]
  (<!! c))
;= :foo
```

The channel is backed by a buffer of size 1 and will be closed after the value returned by the body of the `thread` form is put on it. (Except if the returned value happens to be `nil`, in which case the channel will be closed without anything being put on it -- core.async channels do not accept `nil`.)

This makes `thread` fit in nicely with the rest of core.async. In particular, it means that `go` + the single-bang ops and `thread` + the double-bang ops really are used in the same way in terms of code structure, you can use the returned channel in `alt!` / `alts!` (and the double-bang equivalents) and so forth.

In contrast, the return of `future` can be `deref`'d (`@`) to obtain the value returned by the `future` form's body (possibly `nil`). This makes `future` fit in very well with regular Clojure code not using channels.

There's another difference in the thread pool being used -- `thread` uses a core.async-specific thread pool, while `future` uses one of the Agent-backing pools.

Of course all the double-bang ops, as well as `put!` and `take!`, work just fine regardless of the way in which the thread they are called from was started.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like he is recommending using core. async's built in thread macro  rather than java's Thread class.

http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/thread

Answer (score 1):

Aside from which threadpool things are run in (as pointed out in another answer), the main difference between `async/thread` and `future` is this:

- `thread` will return a channel which only lets you `take!` from the channel once before you just get nil, so good if you need channel semantics, but not ideal if you want to use that result over and over
- in contrast, `future` returns a dereffable object, which once the thread is complete will return the answer *every time you `deref`* , making it convenient when you want to get this result more than once, but this comes at the cost of channel semantics

If you want to preserve channel semantics, you can use `async/thread` and place the result on (and return a) `async/promise-chan`, which, once there's a value, will always return that value on later `take!`s. It's slightly more work than just calling `future`, since you have to explicitly place the result on the `promise-chan` and return it instead of the `thread` channel, but buys you interoperability with the rest of the `core.async` infrastructure.

It almost makes one wonder if there shouldn't be a `core.async/thread-promise` and `core.async/go-promise` to make this more convenient...